# Add/Edit/Delete rows withmultiple select option - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I am using JavaScript to add/delete/edit rows. The row includes 4 textbox and two selection box. The script only works wih only one select box but not with both of them at same time. Can you please help me finding the error in script ?

Below is html

```
<table style="text-align: left; width: 1115px; height: 228px;" border="1" id="data_table" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
    <th>Fee Code</th>
    <th>Fee Name</th>
    <th>Fee Category</th>
    <th>Fee Type</th>
    <th>Payment Frequency</th>
    <th>Fee Amount (in Rs)</th>
    <th>Due Date</th>

    </tr>

    <tr id="row1">
    <td id="ffcode_row1">AF</td>
    <td id="ffname_row1">Annual Fees</td>
    <td id="ffcategory_row1">Admission</td>
    <td id="fftype_row1">Fixed Fee</td>
    <td id="fffrequency_row1">Yearly</td>
    <td id="ffamount_row1" class="ffeetotal">1000</td>
    <td id="ffdate_row1">2016-12-21</td>
    <td>
    <input type="button" id="edit_button1" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('1')">
    <input type="button" id="save_button1" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('1')">
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('1')">
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="row2">
    <td id="ffcode_row2">MF</td>
    <td id="ffname_row2">Medical Fees</td>
    <td id="ffcategory_row2">Medical</td>
    <td id="fftype_row2">Fixed Fee</td>
    <td id="fffrequency_row2">Quarterly</td>
    <td id="ffamount_row2" class="ffeetotal">2000</td>
    <td id="ffdate_row2">2016-12-11</td>
    <td>
    <input type="button" id="edit_button2" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('2')">
    <input type="button" id="save_button2" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('2')">
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('2')">
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="row3">
    <td id="ffcode_row3">TF</td>
    <td id="ffname_row3">Tution Fees</td>
    <td id="ffcategory_row3">General</td>
    <td id="fftype_row3">Fixed Fee</td>
    <td id="fffrequency_row1">Quarterly</td>
    <td id="ffamount_row3" class="ffeetotal">3000</td>
    <td id="ffdate_row3">2016-11-11</td>
    <td>
    <input type="button" id="edit_button3" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('3')">
    <input type="button" id="save_button3" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('3')">
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('3')">
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="new_ffcode"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="new_ffname"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="new_ffcategory"></td>
    <td>
    <select name="fftype" id="new_fftype">
        <option value="">-select-</option>
        <option value="Fixed">Fixed Fee</option>
        <option value="Refundable">Refundable Fee</option>
        <option value="NonRefundable">Non Refundable Fee</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <select name="fffrequency" id="new_fffrequency">
        <option value="">-select-</option>
        <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
        <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
        <option value="Monthly">Quarterly</option>
        <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
        <option value="Yearly">Quarterly</option>
        <option value="One-off">One-off</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="number" id="new_ffamount" class="ffeetotal"></td>
    <td><input type="date" id="new_ffdate"></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="add" onclick="add_row();" value="Add Row"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

The javascipt which I have written is :

```
function edit_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="block";

 var ffcode=document.getElementById("ffcode_row"+no);
 var ffname=document.getElementById("ffname_row"+no);
 var ffcategory=document.getElementById("ffcategory_row"+no);
 var fftype=document.getElementById("fftype_row"+no);
 var fffrequency=document.getElementById("fffrequency_row"+no);
 var ffamount=document.getElementById("ffamount_row"+no);
 var ffdate=document.getElementById("ffdate_row"+no);

 var ffcode_data=ffcode.innerHTML;
 var ffname_data=ffname.innerHTML;
 var ffcategory_data=ffcategory.innerHTML;
 var fftype_data=fftype.innerHTML;
 var fffrequency_data=fftype.innerHTML;
 var ffamount_data=ffamount.innerHTML;
 var ffdate_data=ffdate.innerHTML;

 ffcode.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='ffcode_text"+no+"' value='"+ffcode_data+"'>";
 ffname.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='ffname_text"+no+"' value='"+ffname_data+"'>";
 ffcategory.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='ffcategory_text"+no+"' value='"+ffcategory_data+"'>";
 fftype.innerHTML="<select id='fftype_text"+no+"' value='"+fftype_data+"'><option value>-select-</option><option value='FF'>Fixed Fee</option><option value='RF'>Refundable Fee</option><option value='PF'>Penalty Fee</option><option value='DF'>Discounts</option></select>";
 fffrequency.innerHTML="<select id='fffrequency_text"+no+"' value='"+fffrequency_data+"'><option value="">-select-</option><option value='Daily'>Daily</option><option value='Weekly'>Weekly</option><option value='Monthly'>Monthly</option><option value='Quarterly'>Quarterly</option><option value='Yearly'>Yearly</option><option value=,One-off'>One-off</option></select>";
 ffamount.innerHTML="<input type='number' class='ffeetotal' id='ffamount_text"+no+"' value='"+ffamount_data+"'>";
 ffdate.innerHTML="<input type='date' id='ffdate_text"+no+"' value='"+ffdate_data+"'>";
}

function save_row(no)
{
 var ffcode_val=document.getElementById("ffcode_text"+no).value;
 var ffname_val=document.getElementById("ffname_text"+no).value;
 var ffcategory_val=document.getElementById("ffcategory_text"+no).value;
 var e =document.getElementById("fftype_text"+no);
 var fftype_val=e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
 var f =document.getElementById("fffrequency_text"+no);
 var fffrequency_val=f.options[f.selectedIndex].text;
 var ffamount_val=document.getElementById("ffamount_text"+no).value;
 var ffdate_val=document.getElementById("ffdate_text"+no).value;

 document.getElementById("ffcode_row"+no).innerHTML=ffcode_val;
 document.getElementById("ffname_row"+no).innerHTML=ffname_val;
 document.getElementById("ffcategory_row"+no).innerHTML=ffcategory_val;
 document.getElementById("fftype_row"+no).innerHTML=fftype_val;
 document.getElementById("fffrequency_row"+no).innerHTML=fffrequency_val;
 document.getElementById("ffamount_row"+no).innerHTML=ffamount_val;
 document.getElementById("ffdate_row"+no).innerHTML=ffdate_val;

 document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="block";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="none";
}

function delete_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("row"+no+"").outerHTML="";
}

function add_row()
{
 var new_ffcode=document.getElementById("new_ffcode").value;
 var new_ffname=document.getElementById("new_ffname").value;
 var new_ffcategory=document.getElementById("new_ffcategory").value;
 var new_fftype=document.getElementById("new_fftype").value;
 var new_fffrequency=document.getElementById("new_fffrequency").value;
 var new_ffamount=document.getElementById("new_ffamount").value;
 var new_ffdate=document.getElementById("new_ffdate").value;

 var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
 var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
 var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='ffcode_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_ffcode+"</td><td id='ffname_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_ffname+"</td><td id='ffcategory_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_ffcategory+"</td><td id='fftype_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_fftype+"</td><td id='fffrequency_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_fffrequency+"</td><td class='ffeetotal' id='ffamount_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_ffamount+"</td><td id='ffdate_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_ffdate+"</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button"+table_len+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' id='save_button"+table_len+"' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'></td></tr>";

 document.getElementById("new_ffcode").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_ffname").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_ffcategory").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_fftype").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_fffrequency").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_ffamount").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_ffdate").value="";
}
```

Comment: found the solution...problem was with double quotes included in one of the option

Answer (score 0):

found the solution...problem was with double quotes included in one of the option